# Each div lower than the previous one, no margin or padding issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Creating a custom WordPress theme with Bootstrap3.

My divs are behaving ridiculous, as I probably missed something. I tried various solutions like display: inline, vertical-align: top, floats and clears, etc... But nothing worked.

Here is my current look, and everything should be inline:

[image]

here is my current code:

```
    <div class="container content">
                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 blog-posts">                    
                    <article class="single-article col-md-4">
                    <a href="myweb.com/blog/tempus-non-auctor/">
                    <img width="300" height="300" src="myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/team4-300x300.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="team4" srcset="myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/team4-300x300.jpg 300w, myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/team4-150x150.jpg 150w, myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/team4.jpg 573w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">                    </a>
                    <h1 class="article-headline"><a href="myweb.com/blog/tempus-non-auctor/">tempus non, auctor</a></h1>
                    <h4 class="article-time-stamp"><i>Posted on July 15th, 2016</i></h4>
                    <p></p><p>Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Fusce fermentum. Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Suspendisse feugiat. Praesent congue erat at massa.<br><a class="moretag hvr-pop" href="myweb.com/blog/tempus-non-auctor/"><i>Read more</i></a></p>
<p></p>                    </article>                                       
</div> <!-- end blog posts part -->
<!--END content wrapper -->             
</div>
```

and css:

```
.single-article {
    padding-bottom: 10%;

    em {
        font-style: italic;
    }
}

.article-headline {

    padding-bottom: 2%;

    a {
        color: $purple-color;
    }
}

.article-time-stamp {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

Any advices? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have `col-md-4` nested right under `col-md-12`. You can't nest columns like that. You need a row in between. That is improper Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class"col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `inline-block`, make sure that you have this CSS declaration:

```
vertical-align: top
```

This way everything gets aligned at the top of the div. You can always use margins or padding to push things down if you need to.

Hope this fixes what you need!

Comment: tried that solution and sadly no luck. I cant apply margin or padding individually on each div as I'm generating the content through WordPress. Any other idea?

Comment: @Damir How about using `display: flex` on the parent container? That automatically aligns everything inline and it has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the easiest solution is the most logical one.

I've found out that I had a `<br>` tag under each article and this was causing that each article is being pushed down.